# Event when TcpClient receives data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tcp, stream

Is there any way of detecting new data available in a TcpClient without polling? Either by an event related to the TcpClient or to the Stream used to read it.

Polling wastes resources. So it seems logical that *somewhere* there's an event one can subscribe to, in order to be notified of new data being sent by a server. No polling, no 3rd party libraries, and no unmanaged code. Just simple managed built-in .net. If TcpClient is the wrong tool - that's fine too - what *is* the correct class for this?

Comment: The question is not ASP.NET or C# specific. I recommend that those tags be removed.

Comment: Point taken. But the tags help the answerers give answers that can work in this scenario (e.g. perhaps there's a special Asp.net class for this that I am unaware of). I give as much information in the tags as possible about the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Just use async IO. Async IO is callback based which is very similar to an event.

In a modern style you'd say something like `await myNetworkStream.ReadAsync(...)`. No thread is blocked during that call. If this is the first time you hear of `await` this might sound impossible but it's true.

The callback is invisible here. In the old APM pattern it is clearly visible:

```
myNetworkStream.BeginRead(..., asyncResult => { /* callback code */ });
```

(In these examples I assume that you have obtained an instance of `NetworkStream` from your `TcpClient`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have experience with await (though I have heard of it). Are you saying that it will wait until new information is written to the Stream and only then call the callback? Or are you just saying it will read without blocking? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it looks like the latter. Which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The async read APIs have the same contract as the synchronous ones. The operation completes when there is data available or when the stream is depleted.; To correct your language a bit: Reads do not complete when data is written. Reads complete when data becomes available (when it arrives). Async reads never block (that's the point) but the read only completes when data arrives (or the stream has ended). Then, the callback will be called.

Comment: Yes. I meant "written" - by the server. So I take it that if no data is present - this will wait for it. OK. I need to check this out. Or even the old `BeginRead`. I thought it would simply return null if no data were present.

Comment: Polling and C-style non-blocking IO are not common in the .NET world because, frankly, they almost never are a good idea. Ancient concepts.